# Assign role by running process

Tags: salt-stack

I'd like to assign a role to various minions based on a process that is running. For example I can do this

```
salt '*' cmd.run 'ps ax |grep [n]amed'
```

This returns servers that are running bind, but since it runs against everyone (*) not only do I get the dns servers I also get everyone else, albeit with blank return data. Is there a way to only return the servers where this is true, and then pipe it to grains.setval role nameserver?

Thanks!

Comment: don't you have a named state you applied to get named installed?

Comment: I do, that was just an example. We're bringing up salt in an environment where everything was manually deployed and so trying to rein all that in. I have about 90 servers running a process that i'd like to tag with a role, and using cmd.run for ps seemed the easiest route for me.

Comment: as a one time thing or iteratively?

Comment: This would be a one-off to bring exiting servers under management.

Comment: This feels kind of dirty, but I think will work, let me know if you have something more elegant. 

salt '*' cmd.run 'ps ax |grep [n]amed' --out txt |awk '{print $1}' |sed 's/://' |xargs -n1 -I computer salt computer grains.setval role nameserver

Comment: I'd not be too concerned about it.  if it's a one off that looks perfectly legit to me.

Comment: I like to wrap my cmd.runs inside of a python try / exception to do the run and let me know if a few machines failed.